# How to use subfolders in the Pages and Shared folders

Tags: .net-core, blazor

I've got a Blazor Server-Side application. It has the folders Pages and Shared out-of-the-box. Since I have a lot of components in these folders, I wanted to distribute the components into multiple subfolders for a clearer structure. But if I do this, the components are not found and are not displayed in the GUI.
What am I missing? Do I have to register the routes to the new subfolders somewhere?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can have whatever folder structure you wish. But you will need to update your `_Imports.razor` with the new namespaces.

For example if you have a structure of

```
MyProject/Components/Forms/MyInput.razor
```

You would need the following in your `_Imports.razor`:

```
@using MyProject.Components.Forms;
```

The other option is to reference components using their fully qualified namespace:

```
<MyProject.Components.Forms.MyInput/>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for! And btw I like your blog, it helped me many times already.

Comment: You're welcome, great to hear you're finding the blog useful.

Comment: Just had to bookmark [the blog of Chris](https://chrissainty.com/), too. Thanks for mentioning it here, @PascalR.

Comment: Is that still working in 2020? Visual Studio tells me the .Forms namespace doesn't exist. It's still compiling and working fine, but I can't develop with dozens of false positive error messages in my code.

Comment: Oh man, turning it(Visual Studio) off and on again truly is the duct tape of software engineering...

Answer (score 2):

I am using partial classes for my code and not embedding code in the razor page, so I was a bit confused by the advice from Chris above and kept getting compile errors on my overrides in my partial classes after moving them into a new sub-directory.

**Here is how I got it to work:**

I had a page called *EmployeeList.razor* and a partial class called *EmployeeList.razor.cs* located in a project named Web.Client in the Pages folder.  That means the following:

- The namespace of the *EmployeeList.razor* page by default is Web.Client.Pages
- My partial class is using the same namespace

If I move *EmployeeList.razor* and *EmployeeList.razor.cs* files to a sub-folder **under** Pages called EmployeePages, the *EmployeeList.razor* page will now have a new namespace of Web.Client.Pages.EmployeePages.  That means that I need to also **change my partial class' namespace to match** or it will not be able to override methods.

The only other issue I ran into was not paying attention to the the folder name I used.  I initially used a sub-folder named Employee (as in Pages\Employee\EmployeeList.razor) and this created a namespace for the razor page of Web.Client.Pages.Employee and I started having issues with an Employee.cs class I was using in my partial class since it thinks I'm trying to use a namespace rather than a class name.  Since the path of the page is determined by the @Page directive on the razor page, the folder names really only determine the  namespace of the razor page so I changed the sub-folder name to EmployeePages.

I did not find that I needed to update the _Imports.razor page with the new namespace, but I'll keep it in mind in case things stop compiling properly.