# Can I have multiple _Host.chstml files in Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor

The current default Blazor server side app has  _Host.chstml file on Pages folder. If I dont want to use Pages folder but instead use multiple folders for different sub folders, can I have multiple _Host.chstml file as well?

Comment: You can have several page folders with a single `_host` file. What's the problem?

Comment: OK. So we cannot have multiple _host. SO the host is the point of entry for the app? So if i want to use a different css for a page, I wont put all my css on the _host file but instead put it on Layout, then each layout can have its css. Does it make sense?

Comment: This post answers your question?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/layouts

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to have multiple _Host files. Instead you can create multiple featured sub-folders. See here how to do it: [How to use subfolders in the Pages and Shared folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57112091/how-to-use-subfolders-in-the-pages-and-shared-folders)

You can also define multiple layout components in the Shared folder, for each of your featured sub-folder. Note that in each of these folders there should be an _Imports.razor file with a @layout directive and the name of a custom layout component...Currently, the Pages folder contains an Imports.razor file with a @layout directive set to MainLayout: `@layout MainLayout`

Place your CSS files in the the wwwroot folder.

Hope this helps..